# Is putting std::move inside a lambda really necessary here?

Tags: c++, c++11

Do I really have to encapsulate the std::move call in a lambda?

```
std::list<std::wstring>     srcData = GetData(); // implementation not important
std::vector<std::wstring>   dstData;
dstData.reserve(srcData.size());
std::transform(std::begin(srcData), std::end(srcData), std::back_inserter(dstData), 
    [](std::wstring& guid) -> std::wstring { return std::move(guid); });
srcData.clear();
```

I am still new to lambdas and rvalue references, so initially I tried:

```
std::transform(std::begin(srcData), std::end(srcData), 
    std::back_inserter(dstData), &std::move<std::wstring>);
```

which doesn't work.

Do I have to put the move inside a lambda, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What are your trying to achieve? In this case isn't it sufficient just to use std::copy or std::vector<std::wstring> dstData(srcData.begin(), srcData.end())?

Comment: 2nd that. Additionally, what you tried to do in the part without the lambda is taking the address of the return value of std::move, which acts exactly like a temporary. Taking the address of a temporary is always a bad idea.

Comment: @kyku The point is obviously to *avoid* copying the strings, instead moving the strings. Depending on how std::string is implemented, this may have a big performance advantage.

Comment: @Bob No, std::move is not being called here, its address is being taken. This is supposed to be a function pointer, not an address of a temporary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative is to use move iterators:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> dstData(std::make_move_iterator(srcData.begin()),
                                  std::make_move_iterator(srcData.end()));
```

Or use the `move` algorithm:

```
std::move(srcData.begin(), srcData.end(), std::back_inserter(dstData));
```

---

Since it was asked, here's how you could force the original proposal to work:

```
int main()
{
    std::transform(std::begin(srcData),
      std::end(srcData),
      std::back_inserter(dstData),
      static_cast<std::wstring&&(*)(std::wstring&)>(&std::move<std::wstring&>));
}
```

Comment: Curse you, just posting exactly what I wanted when I discovered this question! :P

Comment: Good answer +1. But I would still like to know why passing `std::move<std::wstring>` as the fourth parameter did not work, it seems like it should.

Comment: @LokiAstari: You'd have to select the correct overload, and also provide an explicit instantiation. I'll add that.

Comment: This is the first time I see move iterators. Thank you.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I believe that the problem is with the choice of template instantiation. The original attempt in the question used `std::move<std::wstring>` but you actually need `std::move<std::wstring&>`. As of the explicit instantiation, I don't see why that would be required... but then again I have not tested it

Comment: @LokiAstari: I think the explicit template instantiation isn't necessary after all. Not sure why I thought it needs to be there. I removed it from the code now, and everything is fully standard-compliant.

Comment: I don't have accesses to a compiler currently. But do you still need the static cast?

Comment: @LokiAstari: Yes. It isn't so much a "cast" as it is a way to select the right overload -- nothing actually gets converted. You can write it as a C-style cast if you feel dirty.